# Upload image using AFNetworking with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" SWift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, afnetworking, image-uploading

I would like to upload image to server from my iPhone application. I am using AFNetworking v 2.6.3
The request content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". 
I have done the following things.

Here is my code

```
let image = imageArray[0]
        let pngImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let imgString = pngImage?.base64EncodedString()
        let parameters : NSDictionary = ["img" : imgString ?? "",
                                         "name" : "imgName.png"]
        let serviceName = ".../UploadBusinessImage"

WebserviceHandler.sharedWebserviceHandler.sendPOSTRequestStream(serviceName,  parameters: parameters, successClosure: { (response) in
            self.logResponse(response)
        }) { (error ) in
            self.logResponse(error.localizedDescription as AnyObject)
        }



webserviceHandler is AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and set as below

class WebserviceHandler {
    var webserviceHandler : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager!
    class var sharedWebserviceHandler: WebserviceHandler {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: WebserviceHandler = WebserviceHandler()
            }
        return Static.instance
    }


init() {
        let baseURL = URL(string:"example.com/")!
        self.webserviceHandler = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL:baseURL)
        self.webserviceHandler.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        self.webserviceHandler.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

        }

func sendPOSTRequestStream(_ serviceName:String, parameters:NSDictionary, successClosure:@escaping WebserviceResultClosure, errorClosure:@escaping WebserviceErrorClosure){
self.webserviceHandler.post(serviceName, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation, responseObj) in
            successClosure(responseObj as AnyObject)
        }) { (operation, error) in
            errorClosure(error as NSError)
        }

}
```

But its not working. How will I handle such request?

Other than the image uploading service all other services are "application/json"